# malloc error: can't allocate region

Tags: cocoa, malloc

i am using xcode 4.2 with ARC on and i keep getting this error:

```
Fly(7258,0x7fff72157960) malloc: *** mmap(size=18446744073709522944) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
```

I have found that this is the area that is causing the problems but i cant see whats wrong:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [lineArray count]; i++) {

    if ([[lineArray objectAtIndex:i]length] >0) {
        if ([[lineArray objectAtIndex:i]characterAtIndex:0]== 'v') {
            if ([[lineArray objectAtIndex:i]characterAtIndex:1]== ' ') {
                for (int b = 0; b <[[lineArray objectAtIndex:i]length]; b++) {
                    int charLoc;
                    if ([[lineArray objectAtIndex:i]characterAtIndex:b] ==' ') {

                        NSString *string = [[lineArray objectAtIndex:i] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(charLoc+1, b-charLoc-1)]; 

                        charLoc = b;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated,
Ben

Comment: Does Cocoa initialize auto variables like charLoc?

Comment: No it doesn't, your absolutely right. Silly me - thanks

Comment: Lots of calls to `objectAtIndex`... that can't be good for performance...

Comment: Yeah? Would it be better if i just created a string with `[lineArray objectAtIndex:i]` and called that?